# How to determine concentration of salt in a salt bridge

Tags: electrochemistry

How do you determine as to what concentration of solution you need for a salt bridge in a galvanic cell? Do you even need a specific concentration in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a downside to using a saturated salt solution to in the bridge, but the higher the salt concentration, the greater the bridge's conductivity and the greater the usable potential of the cell.

Comment: Ok so how concentrated your electrolytes are does not tell you how concentrated the salt bridge should be?